# ag-grid not showing data when dynamically changing the column configurations

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to use ag grid to show data in my component. I am making an API call and then dynamically extracting the data column name from response and passing this information to the child component to display. But it not showing the data.

When I don't use dynamic behaviour and get the static configuration from variable it is working.

Static Column Config =>

```
export let DETIALCONFIG= {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            headerName: 'VT Name',
            field: 'vtName',
            hide: false,
            minWidth: 235,
            serverFlag: true,
            tooltipFields: 'veName'
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Key',
            field: 'KEY',
            hide: false,
            serverFlag: true,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'ID',
            field: 'ID',
            hide: true,
            serverFlag: true,

        },
        {
            headerName: 'APP Name',
            field: 'APP_NAME',
            hide: true,
            minWidth: 140,
            serverFlag: true,

        },
        {
            headerName: 'Status ',
            field: 'Status',
            hide: true,
            minWidth: 200,
            serverFlag: true,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Version',
            field: 'VERSION',
            hide: true,
            minWidth: 235,
            serverFlag: true,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Details',
            field: 'DETAILS',
            hide: true,
            minWidth: 235,
            serverFlag: true,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Json',
            field: 'JSON',
            hide: true,
            minWidth: 235,
            serverFlag: true,
        },
    ],
    gridOptions: {
        domLayout: 'autoHeight',
        pagination: false,
        paginationPageSize: 6,
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        suppressPropertyNamesCheck: true,
        enableBrowserTooltips: true,
        suppressAutoSize: true
    }
}
```

Dynamic Logic

```
  private run = async (veName: string) => {
    let response: any
    try {
      response = await apiCall(veName, [], true)
      this.veTableData = [...response.data]
      const keys = Object.keys(this.veTableData[0])
      this.columnConfig = this.veDetailsGridConfig
      this.columnConfig.columnDefs.map((item: any) => {
        if(keys.includes(item.field)) {
          item.hide = false
          return item
        }
      })
      console.log(this.columnConfig)
      this.tableHeader = veName.toUpperCase()
    } catch (err) {
      this.veTableData = []
      this.columnConfig = this.veDetailsGridConfig
    }
```

with dynamic logic when I try to display this columnConfig in templete inside gripOptions property another columnDefs is getting added every time. It is not happening with static behaviour, and I suppose this is the issue. Can you guys please looks what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is on the below line, when we do map, we need to assign it to another or the same array, else the changes won't get applied

```
private run = async (veName: string) => {
    let response: any
    try {
      response = await apiCall(veName, [], true)
      this.veTableData = [...response.data]
      const keys = Object.keys(this.veTableData[0])
      this.columnConfig = this.veDetailsGridConfig
      this.columnConfig.columnDefs = this.columnConfig.columnDefs.map((item: any) => { // changed here!
        if(keys.includes(item.field)) {
          item.hide = false
        }
        return item;
      })
      console.log(this.columnConfig)
      this.tableHeader = veName.toUpperCase()
    } catch (err) {
      this.veTableData = []
      this.columnConfig = this.veDetailsGridConfig
    }
```

Aggrid generally does not apply the column changes when the inputs are changed, we need to do this small hack.

```
this.gridApi.setColumnDefs([]);
this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.columnConfig.columnDefs);
```

If the columns defs are not detected try using array destructuring to create a new reference for the array, maybe the grid will detect the changes!

```
this.columnConfig.columnDefs = [...this.columnConfig.columnDefs];
```

Comment: @breakingcode could you provide the minimal reproducible example in stackblitz or plunkr using the aggrid examples, it will be good for debugging!

Comment: hey there is one line return statement we need to add after the if block for the item which are not satisfying condition. or else it was showing undefined for them.. Still it not showing the grid, and I can see the columnDefs added inside the gridOptions

Comment: hey I suppose the change we are doing in columnConfig is not getting detected. As I checked onGridReady() event is only getting called once

Comment: hi, the issue is resolved I was not initializing the columnConfig variable when component loads, after initializing it in the constructor it start working, I suppose for change detection to work you need to initialize the variables with some value so that it can detect changes.

Comment: @breakingcode glad its resolved!